# Change battery charge percentage in Windows Phone 8 Simulator

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to develop a Windows Phone 8 application that behaves differently according to the  charge percentage of the phone's battery (stops doing some tasks if the user has a low battery charge percentage).
I would like to test that in Visual Studio's WP8 simulator, but I have no clue on how to change the charge percentage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not.
You have to test it on a real device but keep in mind that if you are in debugging mode you are connected via an USB cable ;) This could falsify your results.

Comment: I understand... Is there any way to stop charging when connected through USB?

Comment: @rhcpfan No, you can't attach the phone via USB and have it use it's own power.